# Como quebrar linhas ao enviar um email?

Tags: php

Como faço para quebrar linhas em um e-mail que será enviado via `PHP` ?

> Se eu utilizar `<br/>` funciona só que o e-mail chega na caixa de spam.

Parte do código PHP:

```
if(count($errors) == 0){
    $user = get_userdata( $status );
    $user->set_role('commentator_commenter');
    $from = get_option('admin_email');  
    $headers = __( 'De', 'commentator' ).' '.$from . "</br>";  
    $subject = __( 'Registrado com sucesso', 'commentator' );
    $msg = __( 'Você foi registrado com sucesso!<br/>', 'commentator' ).__( 'Seus dados:<br/>', 'commentator' ).__( 'Usuário:', 'commentator' ).$username.__( '<br/>Senha:', 'commentator' ).$password;
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    $arr = array(
        'message' => __( 'Registro com sucesso, verifique em seu e-mail a sua senha', 'commentator' )
    );
}
```

Comment: Não é por causa do `<br>` que fica na caixa de *spam*. O espaçamento depende do `content-type` que estiveres a utilizar no envio do email.

Comment: Olá @JorgeB. Eu percebi isso, eu vi que o problema é nos caracteres que estão acentuados, não se pode usar `á, ã, õ, é, etc...` No caso tenho que mudar de `set_html_content_type` para `set_text_content_type` ?

Comment: ou usar os [carateres especiais do HTML](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

Comment: Eu uso `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` assim não tenho esses problemas.
Talvez isto te ajude: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_mail_content_type

Comment: Como poderia implementar texto plano no código acima?

Comment: Transforme seu comentário em resposta :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é por causa do `<br>` que fica na caixa de *spam*.

A quebra de linha depende do `content-type` que estiveres a utilizar no envio do email.

Podes usar `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` assim não tens esses problemas.

Ou então podes fazer assim:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/plain"; '));
```

[Fonte](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_mail_content_type)

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver usando o envio da mensagem em texto plano,
pode usar o seguinte:

```
//...
$msg = __( 'Você foi registrado com sucesso!', 'commentator' ) 
    . "\n" . __( 'Seus dados:', 'commentator' )
    . "\n" .__( 'Usuário:', 'commentator' ). $username
    . "\n" . __( 'Senha:', 'commentator' ). $password;
```

Comment: Como assim texto plano ?

Comment: Você pode enviar mensagens em texto plano  ou em HTML. Que tipo de mensagem você envia?

Comment: Só texto, informando os dados para poder logar.

Comment: então da forma que escrevi dará certo! :D

Comment: Obrigado! ......

Answer (score 0):

Você pode quebrar linhas utilizando  `\n` , não sei te dizer se isso te livra da caixa de spam, até porque isso é bem mais complexo que tags a mais ou a menos no corpo da mensagem.